# Test if string matches django url with params

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to create a templatetag that returns `' active'` if the `request.path` url reverses to some named urls.

This is my templatetag code

```
from django import template
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
import re

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def menu_main_active(context, urls):
    for url in urls.split():
        rev = reverse(url) #### PROBLEM IN THIS LINE ####
        if rev == context['request'].path or (re.search(rev.replace("/x/", "/?.+/"), context['request'].path) and rev != "/"):
            return ' active'
    return ''
```

It takes a "list" of strings (separated by space) and checks if any of those is the name of a url that reverses to the current url in `request.path`

This is how I use it

```
{% load menu_item %}
<li class="has-sub{% menu_main_active 'tape-listing tape-list-active tape-list-scratched tape-list-worm tape-detail' %}">
```

It works great if the named url does not have parameters.

So, how can I modify my templatetag to work with urls that have params, like this one

```
url(r'^tape/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', views.TapeDetail.as_view(), name='tape-details'),
```

The problem is that the line

```
rev = reverse(url)
```

does not use params, and can't do it... and throws this exception:

> NoReverseMatch at /qrf/tape/DRA100/
>   Reverse for 'tape-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: [u'qrf/api/tapes/(?P[^/.]+)/\.(?P[a-z0-9]+)$', u'qrf/api/tapes/(?P[^/.]+)/$']

So I was searching for a way to match the url path to the urls names.

Comment: Can you post a sample `url` that comes out of `urls.split()`

Comment: `['tape-listing', 'tape-list-active', 'tape-list-scratched', 'tape-list-worm', 'tape-detail']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drastically reduce complexity by evaluating the request resolver match object:

```
request.resolver_match.url_name  # 'tape-details'
request.resolver_match.view_name  # 'namespace:tape-details'
```

Solution:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def menu_main_active(context, urlnames):
    if context['request'].resolver_match.url_name in urlnames.split():
        return ' active'
    else:
        return ''
```